# Programacion defensiva

Tags: python, bucles

tengo una duda sobre como utilizar programacion defensiva. Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
print('1.Determinar')
print('2.Promedios')
print('3.Estudiantes Entre cursos')
print('4.Dificultad')
print('5.Salir del programa')

while True:
    try:
        opcion = int(input('Ingrese una opcion del menu para seguir'))
    break
```

lo que quiero hacer que el si el usuario ingresa un numero mayor que cinco o si ingresa una string o float le ensenie un error y que debe de cambiar, pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo. Como puedo utilizar la programacion defensiva para validar la entrada del usuario?

Answer (score 2):

Python permite generar una excepción usando la palabra clave 'raise', en este caso se producirá un error si la el valor introducido es un float o mayor que 5 y se imprimirá un mensaje de error y se volverá a solicitar un valor valido

```py
while True:
    try:
        opcion = int(input('Ingrese una opcion del menu para seguir:'))
        if opcion>5:
            raise
        #Continuas con el código que quieras
        break
    except:
        print("No has seleccionado una opcion valida.")
```

Comment: gracias! no sabia que podia incluir un condicional, me ha servido. GRACIAS!

Comment: @rockyprogrammer si una respuesta resolvio tu problema aceptala

Answer (score 2):

Digamos que tu código esta casi bien, solo falta estructurarlo y agregarle un poco mas.
Al hacer un bloque `try` necesitas colocar un `except` o un `finally`. ya que la sintaxis que das es invalida.

El bloque `except` se ejecuta cuando se genera una excepción, también puedes decirle que excepción tome, ya que este se ejecutara cuando ocurra cualquier excepción, si quieres capturar una excepción en especifico lo puedes especificar `except ValueError` que es el error que se generaría si se pone una letra

El bloque `finally` se ejecutara **Siempre** al finalizar el `try`, asi genere una excepción este bloque se ejecutara.

```
print('1.Determinar')
print('2.Promedios')
print('3.Estudiantes Entre cursos')
print('4.Dificultad')
print('5.Salir del programa')

while True:
  opcion = input('Ingrese una opción del menú para seguir: ')
  try:
    opcion = int(opcion)
    if 0<opcion<=5:
      print("opcion correcta")
      break
  except:
     #pones una advertencia si quieres
     pass
```

Como quieres aplicar programación defensiva, lanzar un error no serviría, lo que se quiere es que el usuario ingrese el valor sí o sí, por lo que la sintaxis `raise ValueError`, la cual genera un error, quedaría obsoleta e innecesaria.